# why dict['port_password']['server_port'] = 126 is correct in this case inPyhton?

Tags: python

Here is the code.

```
config={'port_password':{'server_port':123}}
config['port_password'] = {}
config['port_password']['server_port'] = 126
print(config)
```

config['port_password'] = {}，why does config['port_password']['server_port'] = 126 is correct?

```
#config={'port_password':{'server_port':123}}
config['port_password'] = {}
config['port_password']['server_port'] = 126
print(config)
```

when i comment out the first line,it said:"name 'config' is not defined".why?

Comment: The first line _creates_ a dictionary object, and the next two lines _modify_ it.  If you comment out the first line, the dictionary is never created, and thus there is nothing to modify.

Comment: If you just put 126 on the first line, then the second and third are pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code with annotations:

```
# define a variable "config" referring to a dictionary with one key
# and whose value is another dictionary
config={'port_password':{'server_port':123}}

# lookup the "config" variable and replace its inner dictionary
# with an inner dictionary
config['port_password'] = {}

# look the "config" variable giving a dictionary, then lookup
# "port_password" in that dictionary, giving the inner empty dict
# and set "server_port" to 126 in that inner dict
config['port_password']['server_port'] = 126

# lookup the "config" variable and display the nested dictionaries
print(config)
```

Comment: Very concise! Off-topic aside: I've been binging on the talks you've given especially RE: concurrency that are on Youtube. Thanks for all the great content!

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
config = {'port_password':{'server_port':123}}
```

You define a new dictionary `config`, so this name exists, and you set the key `port_password` with the value `{'server_port': 123}`.

If you remove that line, the `config` variable is undefined and you get `NameError`.

But, on the next line, you write:

```
config['port_password'] = {}
```

So, the value associated with the key `port_password` is now an empty dictionary.

When you write:

```
config['port_password']['server_port'] = 126
```

You are filling this empty dictionary. You set the key `server_port` with the value 126.